# tikz: how to define a flowchart (hexagon) loop shape that keep its width fixed but adapts its height to the text inside it?

Tags: width

I am using following (hexagon) loop definition I found in Stackexchange in my flowchart. When the number of text lines in it increases, the width of the whole shape also increases. I want the width of the shape itself to be fixed. Can you help in defining such a hexagon? It does not have to follow the starting definition I give in the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, shapes.misc, matrix, shapes, arrows, calc, positioning, shapes.geometric, shapes.symbols, shapes.misc, intersections, chains, scopes}


\tikzset{
    loop/.style={ % requires library shapes.misc
        draw,
        chamfered rectangle,
        chamfered rectangle xsep=2cm,
        text width=10em,
    },
}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.6cm]

\node (l1)[loop]{aa};
% node below is wider then the one above. I want the width of the one below to be same as the one above.
\node (l2)[loop,below of=l1]{aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa };

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: Result picture]

Comment: You can keep `chamfered rectangle xsep=2cm` small to make them have equal width. But no sharp edges.

Comment: I am OK with no sharp edges. But arrangement of any attributes like `chamfered rectantle xsep` should be automatic. I think my title is misleading. You do not have to do it with `chamfered rectangle`. I need a hexagon that arranges its height and keeps its width fixed.

Comment: Hence, I changed the title.

Answer (score 1):

> Workaround A (drawing outside the defined style)

I tried to add drawing after the use of `\node` which can be customized outside your `loop` style.

```
%! *latex mal-chamfered.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc, shapes.misc, matrix, shapes, arrows, calc, positioning, shapes.geometric, shapes.symbols, shapes.misc, intersections, chains, scopes}
\tikzset{
    loop/.style={ % requires library shapes.misc
        draw,
        chamfered rectangle,
        %chamfered rectangle ysep=2mm,
        chamfered rectangle xsep=10mm,
        text width=10em, 
        align=center,
    },
}
\begin{document}
\def\malxsep{3mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.6cm]
\node (l1)[loop]{aa};
\node (l2)[text width=10em-0.5em, align=center,below of=l1]{aaa aaa aaa \\aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa \\aaa\\ aaa aaa\\ aaa aaa aaa aaa };
\draw (l2.north west)--($(l2.west)+(-\malxsep,0)$)--(l2.south west)--(l2.south east)--($(l2.east)+(\malxsep,0)$)--(l2.north east)--cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]

---

> **Edit:** Workaround B (drawing inside the defined style)

I used the `\tikzset` to define following: I started to modify the `loop` style, inside that expression I added `append after command`, inside that part I incorporated the `\pgfextra` command and finally I drew a hexagon in the `\node` itself. I enclose the result of my efforts and a preview of it.

```
%! *latex mal-chamfered.tex
\documentclass{article}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\tikzset{
    loop/.style={
        anchor=north,
        text width=10em, 
        align=center,
        append after command={
           \pgfextra{
              \draw (\tikzlastnode.north west)--($(\tikzlastnode.west)+(-\malxsep,0)$)--
                    (\tikzlastnode.south west)--(\tikzlastnode.south east)--
                    ($(\tikzlastnode.east)+(\malxsep,0)$)--
                    (\tikzlastnode.north east)--cycle;
           }% End of \pgfextra...
        },% End of append after command...
    },% End of loop/.style...
}% End of \tikzset...
\begin{document}
\def\malxsep{3mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
\node(l1)[loop]{aa};
\node(l2)[loop] at (l1.south) {A\\B\\C};
\node(l3)[loop] at (l2.south) {aaa aaa aaa \\aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa aaa \\aaa\\ aaa aaa\\ aaa aaa aaa aaa };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe, part 2]

Comment: The picture you posted is what I want, but I would not like to redraw it manually everytime like you did. I need it defined in a tikzset definition, and just reuse it. The shape should nicely grow vertically when needed, but stay with same width.

Comment: Solution B works with a small caveat. E.g. l2.east and l2.west are not right on the line. They are a little inside. E.g. when I do something like `\draw (l2.east) -- (l3.west);` the connector misses the boundary line. Can there be a way to redefine them also?

Comment: The basic shape is still a rectangle (not hexagon) and you can connect its four corners. For now you can use `\draw ($(l2.east)+(\malxsep,0)$) -- ($(l3.west)+(-\malxsep,0)$);`. It would be worth preparing a new pgf shape, perhaps.

Comment: You could see that rectangle in a minute when trying `fill=blue`. It is probably not the best approach of mine. But we can write `\draw[fill=blue]` in the inner part of style.

Comment: No need. I can understand why it is behaving like this. It is just does not answer my question.

Comment: Yes, my proposals are workarounds.